# Processing pixel value of images in which pixel's coordinates are from list of lines

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm working on a task in image processing (python3), hoping to find improvements in algorithm. My task has 2 main specs:

- 3 gray scale images (same size, named A, B, C)
- List of straight line's coordinates (numpy array) ((x,y) is a point's coordinate)

> ```
> [[x1 y1 x2 y2]
>
> ...
>
> [x1n y1n x2n y2n]]
> ```

Processing step:

1. Get all pixels' coordinates of a line into a list (x_i, y_i)
2. Get pixel value (p_x, p_y) of each 3 images (A,B,C) corresponding to coordinates (x_i, y_i). Sum all the values (p_x, p_y) (A, B, C seperately), after that I have (scoreA, scoreB, scoreC)
3. Testing (scoreA, scoreB, scoreC) with some conditions, ignore the line if not satisfied.
4. Repeat those step with other lines.

Currently, my idea is to create a class called "line_obj" to store line information.

```
class line_obj:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.scoreA = 0.0
        self.scoreB = 0.0     
        self.scoreC = 0.0
```

I then create a list of line_obj(s), containing information for each line. After that I use a for loop to to all those above task.

```
for line_obj in line_obj_list:
  #line() method from scikit-image library to retrieve pixel coordinates of a line
    rr, cc = line(line_obj.y1, line_obj.x1, line_obj.y2, line_obj.x2)
    line_obj.scoreA = A[rr,cc].sum()
    line_obj.scoreB = B[rr,cc].sum()
    line_obj.scoreC = C[rr,cc].sum()
```

For this task, I need to make it as fast as possible, not sure if it's optimized. Can you suggest me a better idea? Thank you tons.

Comment: A simple solution is to each line as white on a black background the same size as your images. This becomes a mask that can be used to list all the values in each image where the mask is white (or non-zero).

Comment: @fmw42 I'm afraid drawing white lines on black image to be a mask will require more computations. The line() function is what I find quite straight forward, because it returns exactly pixels coordinates in one line (I think it's faster that drawing a mask and np.where on that mask).

Comment: But then you have to random access the image over an over to get each point value. With a mask and Numpy, you have a vectorized operation. But I leave it to you to test speed as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't understand the structure of your coordinate data. You said it's a numpy array and yet what you wrote is a flat list of coordinates. Whatever it is, it's better to convert it to numpy.
If to imagine you have the following data:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1024, 1024)) #1024 is just example pic size
B = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1024, 1024)) #1024 is just example pic size
C = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1024, 1024)) #1024 is just example pic size

coords = np.random.randint(0, 1023, (200, 4)) #assuming you have 200*2 coords or whatever size the scikit outputs 
#Here I'm assuming x is the rows and y is columns  
A_pix_values_c1 = A[coords[:, 0], coords[: , 1]]  #c1 is coords 1
A_pix_values_c2 = A[coords[:, 2], coords[: , 3]]  #c2 is coords 2
B_pix_values_c1 = B[coords[:, 0], coords[: , 1]]
B_pix_values_c2 = B[coords[:, 2], coords[: , 3]]
C_pix_values_c1 = C[coords[:, 0], coords[: , 1]]
C_pix_values_c2 = C[coords[:, 2], coords[: , 3]]
```

Now I'm guessing since I don't understand quite much what you're trying to do. I'm assuming you wanna sum the pix values of both coords for each image.

```
scoreA = A_pix_values_c1 + A_pix_values_c2
scoreB = B_pix_values_c1 + B_pix_values_c2
scoreC = C_pix_values_c1 + C_pix_values_c2
```

It is better to avoid a loop as much as possible. I'm not much familiar with scikit image, but if you can get all your lines in one go and in one array it is better to do so and then appy the above approach instead of looping through.
for testing, you can use many ways of numpy arrays, e.g.

```
final_scoreA = scoreA[scoreA_condition]
```

Comment: Thank you. The list of straight lines is just list of 2 end points of a line. My problem is to get pixel coordinates, (what the line() function did). It returns the list of pixel coordinates between 2 points of a line, and if I use boolean index, probably I get the list of coordinates of all pixels from all lines (I just need scoreA,B,C for each line).

Comment: I'm thinking about creating an array of all coordinates from all lines, which produces kind of big array (num_of_line, num_of_pixel_in_line,4)